# vsftpd 530 permission denied CentOS6.7

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, centos-6.7

I'm running CentOS 6.7 and I'm trying to successfully establish an FTP connection using vsftpd. Please point me in the right direction!

```
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Command:    USER testuser
Response:   530 Permission denied.
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

I tried checking `/var/logs/messages` and `/var/logs/xferlog` but the log is empty.  I also checked the `home` directory permissions of the local user and made sure that the user was listed in the userlist and not in the denylist

config:

```
local_enable=YES
pasv_address=108.41.178.133
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40010
pasv_promiscuous=YES
pasv_enable=YES 
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `grep -v ^# /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` ? Basically i am asking to share the vsftpd configuration

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like please go to this link for more information (i dont know my login that I posted this question with) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023241/vsftpd-530-permission-denied-centos6-7

Answer (score 3):

> Made sure that the user was listed in the **userlist** and not in the
>   denylist

I think you are referring to `user_list` which by default is a list of users who are denied access without even password prompt

[image]

If that is so, you must add **userlist_deny=NO** to **vsftpd.conf**

i.e. `echo "userlist_deny=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

[The 530 error is because of the user created for ftp]

Generally the new ftp user will have the description for the user as mentioned in the snapshot here to for that when you:  cat /etc/passwd

you will find similar to this :

vsftpd:x:1003:1004:,,,:/home/vsftpd:/bin/bash

"This centered three commas are the culprit.So,remove them."

[How to solve 530 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS0OY.jpg)